# How do you return successful responses from a Promise within an array after cancelling the entire array?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, promise, bluebird, cancellation

Here is some code to clarify what I am trying to accomplish:

```
import Promise from 'bluebird';

function uploadAll(items){
    return Promise.map(items, function(item){
        return upload(item);
    }, {concurrency: 5});
}

function upload(item){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject, onCancel){
        onCancel(){
           /* Abort upload */
        }
    })
    .then(function(response){

    });
}

var items = /* Array of items */
var uploadPromises = uploadAll(items)
                    .then(response){ 
                        /* Do something here with response, 
                        this won't be hit on cancellation */ 
                    }
                    .finally(){ 
                        /* This is the only block that will be hit,
                           is it possible to get responses here? */ 
                    }

/* Event listener on button that activates uploadPromises.cancel() */
```

Now say there are 50 files in the map and 10 files complete uploading before hitting a button that cancels the array of Promises. How would I (can I?) return responses from the already completed uploads?

If there is anything I can do to make the question more clear please let me know, thank you!

Comment: If it's cancelled, you cannot `return` anything at all. What do you intend to do with the partial results?

Comment: That is what I figured but wanted to make sure there wasn't a separate hook that I didn't know about. For this particular case I wanted to simply display a message to the user stating how many successful uploads there were before the promises were cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture completed uploads as your promises resolve:

```
function uploadAll(items) {
    var completed = [];
    var callback = Promise.map(items, function (item) {
        return upload(item)
            .then(function (rx) {
                completed.push(item);
                return rx;
            });
    }, {concurrency: 5});

    return {
        completed: completed,
        callback: callback
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var uploadJob = uploadAll(items);
// Wait for all uploads
uploadJob.callback
    .finally(function () {
        // check uploadJob.completed     
    });
```